# Are the apostrophe placements correct in every example?

Tags: punctuation

Are the apostrophe placements correct in every example?

• two weeks' vacation
• four days' personal time
• three months' sabbatical time
• ten nights' accommodations
• three hours' sleep
• eight months' pregnancy
• eight months pregnant
• five minutes' time
• a penny's worth
• two pennies' worth
• a nickel's worth
• two nickels' worth
• a dollar's worth
• five dollars' worth
• two seconds' time
• five years' probation

Thank you kindly.

Comment: That's what I'm saying, but a so-called English expert in my hometown said that the apostrophes were required. Looks mondo bizarro to me.

Comment: I'm told that if I omit the apostrophes in those, I am 'egregiously wrong'.

Comment: Your examples are not equivalent, some are correct, other's are not. Why don't you narrow it down to one or two example's so we can actually discus's it. No one will be willing to discuss 16 separate cases in a single question.